# How do I display my Core Data values?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I have a basic `UITableView` where I can add items using Core Data as well as delete if needed.

Let's say I add 5 items to the `UITableView`.  I want to also display these five items on another view, preferably a PDF.

What's the best approach to accomplish this?

I'm attempting using `NSUserDefaults` as well, but the only value that is appearing is the last value that is entered.

Here's some of the main code used.  Any advice is appreciated!

This is from the `UIViewController` where I input the text:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext * )managedObjectContext
{
    return [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

-(void)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender
{

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];


    if (_majorTextField.text == nil)
    {
        _majorString = @"";
    }
    else
    {
        _majorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", _majorTextField.text];
        self.task.title = self.majorTextField.text;
        NSUserDefaults * majorDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [majorDefault setObject:_majorString forKey:@"major"];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Here is where I am adding the text on my PDF:

```
 +(void)createPDF:(NSString*)filePath
 {
    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

    NSUserDefaults * majorDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * majorString = [majorDefault stringForKey:@"major"];

    [PDFRenderer drawText:majorString inFrame:CGRectMake(35, 190, 300, 50) fontName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" fontSize:14];

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults only stores one value per key. So you are effectively over-writing the value each time stored for the key "major". Irrespective of this, you should look at NSFetchRequest to fetch the records you need, loop through the results and create your PDF that way. See here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your `NSManagedObjectContext` before you make changes to the represented object in your view controller.  In `saveButtonTapped:` you save the context but only later set `self.task.title ...`  Perhaps I'm missing something; but I think you want save the context after changing `self.task.title`.

In the other views that need to access the managed objects in question, you need to fetch them by constructing an `NSFetchRequest` and executing that request against an `NSManagedObjectContext`.  I can't give any substantial example without knowing more about your model; but that's the basic idea.

Depending on your needs, Core Data may be ideal or it may be overkill.  There's a lot to be gained by using Core Data for your object graph persistence technology - but there's a lot of subtlety. As Apple puts it.  "Core Data is not an entry level technology." (Apple, *"Getting Started with Core Data"*)

We're probably all guilty of this, but you should pass an error object in `[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];` and handle the return value, thusly:

```
NSError *saveError = nil;
if( ![[self managedObjectContext] save:&saveError] ) {
    // do something with saveError
}
```

EDIT:

Core Data is fine for what you describe in your comment.  It's just a matter of understanding the underlying principles of persistent stores, managed object contexts, etc.  What you do get with Core Data are a set of conveniences for displaying data in table views, i.e. `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is the right path for me to take either.  Ultimately I want to have a table I can edit (add rows, delete rows, rearrange), each row is tappable to a detailed view to input more information, and then have all the information display nicely onto a PDF.  Is there another method you, or anyone else, can recommend to accomplish this?